# ocaml constructing module (super beginner)

Tags: module, ocaml

I'm new to module programming using ocaml. I made a dictionary module such as

```
module type DICT =
  sig
    type key
    type 'a dict
    ...
    val lookup : 'a dict -> key -> 'a option
    ...
  end


module DictList : DICT with type key = string =
  struct
    type key = string
    type 'a dict = (key * 'a) list

    ...
    **let rec lookup d k =
        match d with
        | [] as dict -> None
        | (key, value)::tl as dict -> if( key = k ) then (key, value)
                                      else lookup tl k**
    ...
  end
```

lookup d k searches the key k in the dictionary d. If the key is found, it returns the item, otherwise, it returns None. However, I got a error which says

> Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b
>          but an expression was expected of type 'c list

at lookup function.
What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here (and none of them give the error you claim you're getting).

**1st problem**: your `lookup` function doesn't have consistent type

One branch returns `None` so the type should be `'a option`.
Another branch returns `(key, value)` so the type should be `'a * 'b`.

How to fix? Change `(key, value)` to `Some (key, value)`.

Unfortunately, there is also

**2nd problem**: your `lookup` function does not correspond to its definition in module type.

If you look at your definition of `DICT`, you'll see that `lookup` is `'a dict -> key -> 'a option`.

Now, in your definition of `DictList` module `key` is `string`, so `lookup` should be `'a dict -> string -> 'a option`, where `a` is the type of values you are storing in your dictionary. It means that you cannot return `Some (key, value)`, as then `lookup` will have signature `'a dict -> string -> (string * 'a) option`. Return just `Some value`.

So, your definition should look like

```ml
module DictList : DICT with type key = string =
    struct
    type key = string
    type 'a dict = (key * 'a) list
    let rec lookup d k =
        match d with
        | [] -> None
        | (key, value)::tl -> if (key = k) then Some value else lookup tl k
    end
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood something. Since the definition of lookup is   `('a dict -> key -> 'a option)` and the definition of dict is  `(key * 'a) list`. Therefore I think the return value should `(key * 'a) `which is `'a`  .

Comment: No, you are wrong. Let's say `'a` is `int`. Then the type of `lookup` (as defined in module type) is `int dict -> key -> int option`. What is `int dict` -- that's another story, but `lookup` is already defined as something returning `int option`.

Comment: Notice that you do not define *what exactly* is `'a dict` type in the module type; you can perfectly have implementation of `DICT` which defines `'a dict` as `int`, and `lookup d k` as a function which always returns `Some (some constant value from type 'a)`. It wouldn't do any good, but it will fit the module type as well.

Answer (score 0):

All branches of the `match` expression in `lookup` should have the same type - which corresponds to the return type of `lookup`: `'a option`. So the "found" case should return `Some value` instead of `(key, value)`.